# Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount cmdlet not found in AzureRM.KeyVault v. 3.1.0

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

According to [Powershell Gallery](https://msconfiggallery.cloudapp.net/packages/AzureRM.KeyVault/3.1.0) the 3.1.0 version of AzureRM.KeyVault contains cmdlets supporting Azure Storage accounts whose keys are managed by KeyVault. I installed and Get-Module shows the 3.1.0 version, but I am not seeing (in ExportedCommands) the various commands to support storage.

Comment: How did you install the module? If you used update-module and didn't restart your session it could still be referencing the old version of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I would do.

1. Shutdown all powershell processes or reboot
2. Go to c:\program files\windowspowershell\modules and delete the folder with the `AzureRM.keyvault` in name
3. Launch powershell and install the module `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.KeyVault`

Comment: Turned out it was a bit more than this, but it got me on the right track.  There were versions of AzureRM.KeyVault in four different places. After getting that under control and setting up a profile, it's working.

Comment: You may also need to install the `PowerShellGet` module _first_ so it can find the KeyVault module. Secondly, if you already have an older version installed (e.g. 2.1.0), you may just want to run `Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber` instead of fiddling with updates.

Comment: alternatively if you use docker there is a docker image thats being updated: https://hub.docker.com/r/azuresdk/azure-powershell/